# ArrayList to JList - More than one object element

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, jlist, listmodel

I'm using Eclipse, programming in Java. The problem:

This is how I want my JList to be displayed:

```
1 - Dante
2 - William
3 - Jaime
etc...
```

Now, the numbers are the IDs of the objects, and the names are, well, the names.

ArrayList is named TraitList.

This is what I get when I put that as the "model" property in the JList from the Window Builder in Eclipse:

```
TraitL.setModel(new AbstractListModel() {
        String [] values = new String[] {"1 - Dante", "2 - William", "3 - Jaime"};
        public int getSize() {
            return values.length;
        }
        public Object getElementAt(int index) {
            return values[index];
        }
    });
```

So I changed it for:

```
TraitL.setModel(new AbstractListModel() {
        String [] values = new String [];
        for (int jln = 0; jln < TraitList.size(); jln++){
            values [jln] = (TraitList.get(jln).id + " - " + TraitList.get(jln).Name);
        }
        public int getSize() {
            return values.length;
        }
        public Object getElementAt(int index) {
            return values[index];
        }
    });
```

It didn't work. I've tried dozens of variants. None worked. So, how do I make multiple elements of an object be displayed by this list? I don't care if it's DefaultListModel or AbstractListModel, or even ListModel.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Errors of all lines with what I've tried are in the following image:
[image: errors]

BONUS QUESTION:
How do I make clicking in an element of this list an "actionPerformed" so something happens after I click it?

Comment: This question would be easier to answer if you'd actually say what errors you're getting.  Anyway, one possible source of problems (other than the error mentioned in Guilherme's answer) would be whether  `id` and `Name` are public fields in the class that `TraitList` is a list of.  If they're not, then you may need to use their getters to retrieve them.  And if they are, you should probably read up on encapsulation.

Comment: Added errors with Guilherme's suggestion to the question as an image.
Also, I haven't given classifications as public nor private to the fields in the Trait class, so I guess they are public. I'll read encapsulation. Studied it a long time ago, don't remember it clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new AbstractListModel() {
    String [] values = new String [];
    for (int jln = 0; jln < TraitList.size(); jln++){
        values [jln] = (TraitList.get(jln).id + " - " + TraitList.get(jln).Name);
    }
    public int getSize() {
        return values.length;
    }
    public Object getElementAt(int index) {
        return values[index];
    }
}
```

This is an invalid anonymous class definition, you've got code floating around in the class body.

It can be fixed by either moving the initialization to a private method:

```
String [] values = initTraitList();
private String[] initTraitList() {
    String [] values = new String [TraitList.size()];
    for (int jln = 0; jln < TraitList.size(); jln++){
        values [jln] = (TraitList.get(jln).id + " - " + TraitList.get(jln).Name);
    }
    return values;
}
```

or by using an instance initialisation block:

```
String [] values = new String [TraitList.size()];
{
    for (int jln = 0; jln < TraitList.size(); jln++){
        values [jln] = (TraitList.get(jln).id + " - " + TraitList.get(jln).Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kiskae!
I did solve my problem, but something else went wrong when I went on to test it.
Thanks a lot, anyways, that's one less problem for me to worry with! ^^

Comment: @Werneck If code suddenly triggers an avalanche of warnings and errors the source is usually at the beginning. Thats a good thing to remember when figuring out problems like this.

Comment: Just couldn't figure out how to give the values for the String vector. The return values; line did it for me.

Comment: Thanks again Kiskae! This was an awesome tip! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the line

```
String [jln] = (TraitList.get(jln).id + " - " + TraitList.get(jln).Name);
```

should be

```
values[jln] = (TraitList.get(jln).id + " - " + TraitList.get(jln).Name);
```

right?

Comment: Thanks Guilherme, for your response!
I tried it and also marked the errors as David Wallace asked. It's in the image in the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to copy your list to a local variable. You can if you wish but it's not necessary. Here's an example of accessing the original list directly in your model:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> values = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
    JList list = new JList(new AbstractListModel() {
        public int getSize() {
            return values.size();
        }

        public Object getElementAt(int index) {
            return index + " - " + values.get(index);
        }
    });
    list.addListSelectionListener(e -> 
            System.out.println("Clicked " + list.getSelectedValue()));
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("List Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(list);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

If you particularly want it in an array inside the model with the indices embedded in the value, then:

```
String[] valueCopy = IntStream.range(0, values.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> i + " - " + values.get(i))
    .toArray(new String[0]);
public int getSize() {
    return valueCopy.length;
}

public Object getElementAt(int index) {
    return valueCopy[index];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sprinter.
I marked Kiskae's answer as the most helpful because it felt simpler to me, but it helped a lot to have your answer too, since it gave me an example of action after clickin a list element.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved without a model:

```
String [] values = new String[] {"1 - Dante", "2 - William", "3 - Jaime"};
JList jlist = new JList(values);
scrollpane = new JScrollPane(jlist);
scrollpane.setViewportView(jlist);
```

Comment: "1 - Dante
 2 - William
 3 - Jaime"
was just an example of how I wanted it displayed. Plus I did it to see how would the Window Builder create the JList.
Also, the last two lines are there by default when creating a JList.